# totally confused about editing wp theme....new guy to wp

Tags: themes

i am new to WordPress and i am really confused about editing the theme contents which the WordPress environment doesn't provide, just like Wix would do, i need to remove entirely every content that came with my theme except the backgrounds.

Comment: Please [improve your question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). Summarize your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here there are 3 scenarios:

**1-** You want to customize your current theme. You can do this by heading to `Appearance > Customize` in the left sidebar. You can customize your theme there, based on the theme's design.

**2-** You want to change the theme's structure. If you are familiar with HTML, CSS and PHP, you can start in WordPress [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) to learn how to use functions, filter, loops, etc. Then you can greatly customize your theme. Everything you need is in the codex.

**3-** You are new to web development, and you don't have time to learn it, then you can either choose a free or premium theme, or hire somebody to design your theme the way you want. There are plenty of free themes in the WordPress's theme store `(Appearance > Themes)` , or premium ones in places such as [Theme Forest](https://themeforest.net/).